# react-chartjs chart renders without colors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-chartjs

I've tried making a radar chart using react-chartjs (https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs). It renders, but there are no colors.

[image]

What am I missing? I pretty much copied a large chunk of the example at https://reactcommunity.org/react-chartjs/index.html. (I simplified the data to one dataset.)

```js
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {Grid} from 'react-bootstrap';
const {Radar} = require("react-chartjs");
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

function rand(min, max, num) {
 var rtn = [];
 while (rtn.length < num) {
  rtn.push((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
 }
 return rtn;
}

var chartData = {
 labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
 datasets: [
 {
  label: "My First dataset",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,0.2)",
  borderColor: "red",
  pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
  pointBorderColor: "#fff",
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(179,181,198,1)",
  data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
 }
 ]
};

var chartOptions = {
 scale: {
  reverse: true,
  ticks: {
   beginAtZero: true
  }
 }
};

function TasteGraph({rating}) {
 //loop through and output one slider and one value per component
 return (
  <div>
  <Radar data={chartData} options={chartOptions}/>
  </div>
  );

}
TasteGraph.propTypes = {
 rating: PropTypes.array
};

TasteGraph.defaultProps = {
 rating: []
};

export default TasteGraph;
```

There doesn't seem to be any imports missing or clear error. I tried surrounding the chartOptions and ChartData with "[" and "]" based on another related SO question.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `backgroundColor` with `fillColor`. Propably your `borderColor` should be also replaced with `strokeColor`. 
See in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barbsan/nwdvocp7/60/). (It uses chart.js without react wrapper - but your properties gave same output as in your screenshot)